# Windows 7 Update Fails with 80070013

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Two weeks ago, my mom got some Windows updates on her Windows 7 computer. They downloaded successfully, and when the machine was restarted, everything went okay as it was shutting down. However, when it began booting, it made it to 7% and then said that it could not install the updates and was reverting changes. There are now more Windows 7 updates waiting to be installed, and they are all failing.

Below are the two updates causing the problem:
KB2952664
KB4025341

From the error log, here is the line where it failed:

```
2017-07-30  18:00:22:239     984    b4c Service FATAL: Failed to validate pre-WSUS 3 service registration requests, hr=80070013
```

The first thing I did was run a security scan; this came up clean.

Next, I downloaded and ran the MS update fix-it tool; it came up with several errors, and fixed a few of them. The one it could not fix was something about the service registration being corrupted.

After that, I reset all the update components. The script I used ran and exited successfully, but the issue remained with absolutely no change. I checked the log of the security software, and it was not blocking everything. There are no third-party firewalls. Nothing new has been installed. All updates up to this point have been installed successfully.

I am thinking about trying to reset the update components in safe mode. Is this is a good idea?

I have looked into system restore, but I am a little hesitant to do that since it could mess up her applications. I do not want to do a reinstall unless there is nothing else we can do. My main reason is because she uses MS Office (which I believe was preinstalled on the computer when she bought it), and she does not have the product key or install disc. (Although I found an article that could allow me to get both if needed)

If anyone needs any more info, just ask.
Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: The error means 'Media is write-protected'.

Comment: Have any idea why I am getting this error? There are no issues writing to the hard-drive.

Comment: Your asking one update that was released 3 years ago and another released on July 11th.  The only one likely actually applicable is the Nuly 11th patch

Comment: @Ramhound Microsoft has released the 2952664 update multiple times (with changes, it sounds like); all Windows 7 updates up to this time have been installed on the computer.

Comment: @pdf4664 Microsoft doesn't release the same update (with the same number) multiple times, if that happens they pull the original update, and supersed it with a new number